# KeyDown map to GUI form button downstate

Tags: vb6

Hi I would like to ask if it's possible to map the KeyDown for keyboards in Visual Basic 6 to turn the state of a graphical Command Button on the form to the "Down State" while keyboard key is pressed then back to raised when released? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am aware of the problem here, because I did somewhat similar in the past and ended up by using an array of `PictureBoxes` instead of graphical `CommandButtons`.

Anyway, a simple workaround with `CommandButtons` is to keep the focus away by adding to the `Form` another control which can act as focus target. Remember: when a `Form` goes activated, it will place the focus to the first focusable control inside itself.

As You haven't specified in Your question what kind of keyboard state You need, below is a simple example with the <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd> keys. You will need less than 5 minutes to get it up and running.

**Step 0:**

Copy and paste following declarations to Your VB `Form`:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 0

Const BM_SETSTATE = &HF3    
Private Declare Function PostMessage Lib "user32" Alias "PostMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long

Dim Target(254) As Long
```

**Step 1:**

Add to Your `Form` an array of `CommandButtons` called, for instance,  *Button(0)*, *Button(1)*, *Button(2)*, *Button(3)* and so on.
Set the properties which You need (Picture, DownPicture, etc.) and set also:

```
 TabStop: False
```

Double-click one of this `CommandButtons`. You can see, You have just one entry point for the whole array of Controls. Choose `GotFocus` from the event drop-down and put this piece of code:

```
Private Sub Button_GotFocus(Index As Integer)
    PicFocus.SetFocus
End Sub
```

**Step 2:**

On Your VB `Form`, set this property:

```
 KeyPreview: True
```

Double-click the `Form`, choose `Load` from the event drop-down and set Your desired mapping between a `KeyCode` and the corresponding `CommandButton`:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Target(65) = Button(0).hwnd  ' 65: KeyCode for "a"
    Target(83) = Button(1).hwnd  ' 83: KeyCode for "s"
    Target(68) = Button(2).hwnd  ' 68: KeyCode for "d"
    Target(70) = Button(3).hwnd  ' 70: KeyCode for "f"
End Sub
```

Choose `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` from the event drop-down and put inside the two global keyboard event handlers this piece of code - respectively -1 for the down-state and 0 for the up-state:

```
Private Sub Form_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    ' Debug.Print KeyCode
    Call PostMessage(Target(KeyCode), BM_SETSTATE, -1&, 0&)
End Sub

Private Sub Form_KeyUp(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    Call PostMessage(Target(KeyCode), BM_SETSTATE, 0&, 0&)
End Sub
```

**Step 3:**

Lastly, add to the same VB `Form` the `PictureBox` mentioned above and set following properties:

```
 Name: PicFocus 
 Appearance: 0-Flat 
 BorderStyle: 0-None 
 HasDC: False
 TabIndex: 0 
 TabStop: False 
 Width: 255 
 Left: -1000
```

---

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> and test if this is what You need.

Answer (score 0):

The CommandButton control has mouse and keyboard down and up events:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Debug.Print "click"
End Sub

Private Sub Command1_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
  Debug.Print "keydown"
End Sub

Private Sub Command1_KeyUp(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
  Debug.Print "keyup"
End Sub

Private Sub Command1_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
  Debug.Print "mousedown"
End Sub

Private Sub Command1_MouseUp(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
  Debug.Print "mouseup"
End Sub
```